# Guitar Pedal Components (DIY)

Tags: guitar

After scouring the internet, I could not find the answer to this question. That is, to learn what particular pieces make certain sounds or alter sounds created (Ex. capacitor x tends to make the the pedal fuzzier). Maybe this is a ridiculous question and there is no exact answer, but if anyone can provide assistance in choosing parts for different builds.

Thanks! (All advice appreciated) :D